# $|x^*Ax|\leq |\lambda_{\max}|$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

Where $\|x\|_2=1$ and $A$ is an arbitrary $\mathbb C^{m\times m }$ matrix. Can you give me a proof or counterexample of this statement?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if $\lambda_{max}$ is the largest **singular value** of $A$.  It's not true for eigenvalues (of non-normal matrices), e.g. try $A = \pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 0 & 0\cr}$ whose only eigenvalue is $0$.

EDIT: Write the SVD as $A = U \Sigma V^*$, where $U$ and $V$ are unitary, and $\Sigma$ diagonal with nonnegative entries $\sigma_j \le \lambda_{max}$.  Then
$$\eqalign{|x^* A x| &= |(U^* x)^* \Sigma (V^* x)|\cr &= \left|\sum_j (U^* x)_j \sigma_j (V^* x)_j\right| \cr &\le \lambda_{max} \sum_j |(U^*x)_j| |(V^* x)_j| \cr \text{(by Cauchy-Schwarz)}\ &\le \lambda_{max} \|U^*x\| \|V^*x\|\cr &= \lambda_{max} \|x\|^2}$$

Comment: Can you give me a proof why it's hold true when $\lambda_{max}$ is the largest singular value?

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  For a counterexample, try
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&2\\0&1}
$$
whose only eigenvalue is $1$. Taking $x = \frac 1{\sqrt{2}}(1,1)$, we find $x^*Ax = 2 > 1$.

Comment: So this statement are only true for hermitian matrix?

Comment: The statement will necessarily hold if $A$ is normal.  Rayleigh's theorem exploits the fact that this works whenever $A$ is Hermitian.

Comment: If you're interested in the more general properties of $x^*Ax$ (depending on $A$), then look into the [numerical range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_range) of a matrix.

Comment: For the singular value upper bound: it suffices to note that $|x^*Ax| \leq \|x\| \, \|Ax\| \leq \sigma_{max}(A) \|x\|^2$